# How can you update a SQL value by subtracting a variable from it

Tags: sqlite

```
sqlstring = """
    UPDATE tblInventory SET quantityInStock -= ? WHERE itemID == ? VALUES (?,?)
                """
    values = (p_quantity, p_id)
    runsql(sqlstring, values)
```

I want to update the quantity in stock of the item based on how many items the user decides to purchase.

I was going to just subtract the quantity they user chooses to purchase from the current quantity in stock, but it seems `-=` doesn't work in SQL. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like that:

```
sqlstring = """
    UPDATE tblInventory SET quantityInStock = quantityInStock - ? WHERE itemID = ?
            """
values = (p_quantity, p_id)
runsql(sqlstring, values)
```